# Solve the non-exact differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

I have an exercise and I have an idea of how to solve it, could you help me by giving me a hint?

> $$(10-6y+e^{-3x})d x- 2 d y=0, \qquad y(0)=1$$

This is my attemp

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = P(x,y)\\
    \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = Q(x,y)$$
Is not exact, so find $\mu(x)$
$$ \frac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}}{Q}  = 3 $$
Therefore
$$ \mu (x) = e^{\int 3 dx} \implies e^{3x}$$
Solving
$$ (10-6y+e^{-3x})dx- 2 dy=0\\
e^{3x}[ (10-6y+e^{-3x})dx- 2 dy=0]\\
(10e^{3x}-6ye^{3x}+1)dx-2e^{3x}dy = 0\\
10\int e^{3x}dx-6y\int e^{3x}dx+\int dx = 2e^{3x} \int ydy$$
And in the last line is my doubt, I dont know how to separate the equation.

Thank you

Comment: The second last line is an exact equation.  I don't think it's separable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes those problems that are written as though they could be exact differentials are actually trick questions, and it's easier to solve by a different method.

So in your case, I would divide through by $dx$ and rewrite the equation as
$$y' +3y =\frac{ e^{-3x}}{2} +5.$$ Is this enough of a hint for you to know what to do to solve?

Comment: Oh thank you, it had a trick and it was easier than I thought.